# Recurse Subversion properties

Tags: svn

I thought this would be simple, but I'm struggling. I want to manage Subversion properties recursively, so in a directory and all files and dirs that it contains.

In this particular case I'm trying to *delete* certain properties recursively, but I'm interested in the generic pattern.

Does Subversion provide a tool for this (like `svn propdel -R`)? I couldn't find any in the docs. If not, what would be the easiest way to shell-script my way out of this?

**FYI**: Max OS X, subversion 1.6.x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `svn help propdel`, it supports the `-R` switch:

```
Valid options:
  -R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
```

Comment: d’oh, how did I miss that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From the help (shortened to relevant part):

> svn help propdel

```
...
Valid options:
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  -R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
```

...

Then yes, you can use `-R` or `--recursive`.

So this should work:

```
svn propdel svn:externals . -R
```